# How to create a identification code or key for web？

Tags: security, encryption

I use IP, USERID, DATETIME to create security code in my web App. I want to know more information about how to create security code, e.g:

```
string str="192.168.0.1,myid,20121227,12345";
```

Then I encrypt a string:

```
string strC=encrypt(str);
```

Then string `strC` is my security code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you use the good solution.sometime we need to know about content of our key, so as you did use a encryption method (because there is a decryption method for each encryption method)
sometime we just need a key to assign it to our users , so in these cases we can use one-way algorithms like hash.Finally i say you use a good way but i have another offer for your solution(maybe you have keep this offer in your mind).

change you encrypt /decrypt method like this :

```
private string Encrypt (string str)
{

//Encryption str
//...


return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(EncryptedStr);

}


private string Decrypt (string str)
{

str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);

//Decryption str
//...

return DecryptedStr;

}
```

this will improve your solution and by these method you can use your key in query string variables

Regard , Ali

Comment: 3KS! I want to know about your solution in you app.

Comment: sorry during the answer my reply posted accidentally.I complete it and pot it again

Answer (score 0):

If, by "security code", you really mean "certified identifier", then you don't even need to encrypt anything; what you really want is a [Message Authentication Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). This is an integrity-preserving mechanism which tells you that "the identifier which the user is presenting is an identifier that I created".

If, by "security code", you really mean "session key", then again there is no need to encrypt: take some information about the session and combine it with plenty of random data (from e.g. java.security.SecureRandom) using a cryptographic hash function. This will create an encryption key which is both unique and unguessable. Better still would be a proper key exchange algorithm like Diffie-Hellman, unless you need to worry about middleperson attacks, in which case you need some form of [authenticated key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol#Authentication).

So... what do you mean by "security code"?